# Finding specific piece of line which are available under { } (TCL)

Tags: tcl

I have a file which contains lots of data like :

```
##########################################################
World is great
world has lots of counties
I am john who is staying in world
World {
abcd123 {
how are you 
}

abcd456 {
how is life
}

abcd789 {
what are you doing 
}

}
Hey going for moive
The life in this world is superb
#############################################
```

I want to get information present under "world" only like 
I want output as :

```
abcd123 {
how are you 
}

abcd456 {
how is life
}

abcd789 {
what are you doing 
}
```

only.

Comment: No time to answer properly, but `info complete` will be useful.

Comment: This sort of tasks is usually solved by writing a parser which scans the input character-by-character and maintains a state machine. For this task the parser will not be complicated.

Comment: How do you know that the first line (starts with "World ") is not important, but the 4th (starts with "World {") is?

Answer (score 1):

```
set f [open filename r]
set contents [read -nonewline $f]
close $f

if {[info complete $contents]} {
  # safe to treat string as a list
  for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $s] - 1} {incr i} {
    if {[lindex $s $i] eq "World" && [llength [lindex $s $i+1]] > 1} {
      puts [lindex $s $i+1]
    }
  }
}
```

or, perhaps this is something like Donal's suggestion

```
set f [open $filename r]
set collecting false
set data ""
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
  if {[regexp {^\s*World\s+\{\s*$} $line]} {
    set collecting true
  }
  if {$collecting} {
    append data $line \n
    if {[info complete $data]} break
  }
}
close $f
puts [lindex $data 1]
```

Comment: My problem was though I new how to parse out the lines, I didn't know how to determine which was the important one. That information was never revealed…